# Page not full width on certain mobile devices

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to fix the width of a mobile view. The below linked page displays correctly on most devices (more than 400px wide), but has a margin on the right side of the header on devices with less than 400px horizontal, like the Iphone 6, Iphone 5 and Galaxy S5. The html element says to be the same width as the screen, but when hovering over it, the visual indicator displays otherwise.

I've tried hiding elements to see which element is the problem, but I have not been succesful in finding the problem. I'm hoping one of you might have some insight in the problem at hand.

Screenshot of the problem:

[image]

In this screenshot the header is not full width, while the content is. So the problem seems to be in the header somewhere.

The page is https://www.matrastopper.eu/bestellen/.
I'm assuming some part of the page is scaling problematic on small screens, but I can't find which.

Comment: Have you checked using the Dev Tools? It may help you determine what element is producing the issue

Comment: your divs are full width.. but some divs width is beyond 100% due to margins ..

Comment: @Tesseract I've used them, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this width

```
.no-columns .box.right {
    background-image: url("/media/layout/box-right.gif");
    width: 380px;/* change this width */
}
```

this css 
https://www.matrastopper.eu/css/screen201410.css?

line no  836

Comment: Thanks so much! That fixed it.